# View is not accessible by talkback after animation

Tags: android, android-animation, accessibility, talkback

Facing a very strange issue and not able to find any solution here or any other blogs.

Initially, a view is invisible and using **AlphaAnimation** and **ScaleAnimation** making it visible.

**Animation Code**

```
public void scaleView(View v, int delay) {

        AnimationSet animatorSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animatorSet.setFillAfter(true);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator());

        AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        animation1.setDuration(200);
        animation1.setStartOffset(delay);

        ScaleAnimation fadeIn = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        fadeIn.setDuration(200);
        fadeIn.setStartOffset(delay);

        animatorSet.addAnimation(animation1);
        animatorSet.addAnimation(fadeIn);

        animatorSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                v.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
                v.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });


        v.startAnimation(animatorSet);

    }
```

**View**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llContainerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/app_bg_f8"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlFacebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lbl_login_with_facebook"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLoginWithFacebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_facebook_login_32"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_48">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook_logo" />

        <View
        style="@style/ShadowVertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFacebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/lbl_login_with_facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLoginWithFacebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/llLoginWithFacebook"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/llLoginWithFacebook"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/llLoginWithFacebook"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/llLoginWithFacebook"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_ripple_32" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My efforts on making it accessible

1) Added Content Description:

```
android:contentDescription="@string/lbl_login_with_facebook"
```

2) Adding a content description in view is enough but still, it was not working so after animation add I add focus and told the compiler that it is important by the following snippet:

```
v.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
v.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

But still, no luck to get focus. Can anyone help me to figure out how to make it accessible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a simple mistake in your code. Try changing this:

```
v.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

to this

```
v.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I changed code but it is not working.

Comment: @Nil do you get solution ?